# Typing variadic arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

I was writing a utility function which is closer to lodash `zip` but since I only wanted to pass arguments type of `[any, Error[]]` I decided to write my own function which is something similar to this:

```
function zip<T>(...args: Array<[T, Error[]]>) {
  return args.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      acc[0].push(cur[0]);
      acc[1].push(...cur[1]);
      return acc;
    },
    [[], []] as unknown as [T[], Error[]],
  );
}
```

But unfortunately it's not correct at all.
What I basically want is pass parameters like `zip([2,[]], [{a:'a'},[new Error('a')]], [null, [new Error('crucial error'),new Error('null pointer')]])` and get result `[[2,{a:'a'},null],[new Error('a'), new Error('crucial error'),new Error('null pointer')]]` and want to get correct types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Error` is a type and, therefore, you're not supposed to pass it as a value in the arguments of `zip`. Instead of

```
zip([2, Error[]], [{a:'a'}, Error[]], [null, Error[]])
```

it should be (I'm adding an actual error on this example)

```
zip([2, []], [{a:'a'}, []], [null, [ new Error('got null!!') ]])
```

---

Having sorted that out, you want your function to infer a return type tuple `[ T[], Errors[]]` when passed zero or more tuples `[T, Error[]]` as arguments

```
function zipFN<T>(...args: Array<[T, Error[]]>)  {
    return args.reduce<[T[], Error[]]> (
        (acc, [value, errors]) => {
            acc[0].push(value);
            acc[1].push(...errors);
            return acc;
        },
        [[], []]
    );
}
```

Let's declare the tuple types:

```
type TParam<T> = [T, Error[]]

type TOutput<T> = [T[], Error[]]
```

The function signature is now

```
function zipFN<T>(...args: TParam<T>[] ) : TOutput<T>
```

We can see this function enforces type constraints and infers return type but  fails its inference when passed a non homogeneus set of arguments:

```
let zpt0 = zipFN<string>( ['a', []], [3, []] )    
// OK, it enforces type
// Error: type number is not assignable to type string

let zpt1 = zipFN( [2, []],    [3, []] )
// OK typeof zpt2 is [number[], Error[]]

let zpt2 = zipFN(['a', []], [3, []] )    
// Error: type number is not assignable to type string
// NOT OK, it should infer a union output [(string|number)[]
```

Type inference for a rest parameter (therefore, an array) will take only the first item in consideration, *unless the rest parameter is a generic in itself instead of an array of generics*. If we rewrite the function as

```
function zip2FN<T, P extends TParam<T>[]>(...args: P): TOutput<T>
```

It still doesn't do what's expected:

```
let failedUnion = zip2FN([2, []], ['A', []])
// NOT OK. Type is [unknown[], Error[]]
// but it should be [(string|number)[], Error[]]
```

So our final step is  typing the output conditionally to *infer* from the rest parameters in its *extends* clause ([See TS 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types))

```
type TOutput<P> = P extends TParam<infer I>[]
  ? [I[], Error[]]
  : [P[], Error[]]

function zip3FN<T, P extends TParam<T>[]>(...args: P):  TOutput<P>  {        
    return args.reduce (
        (acc, [value, errors]) => {
            acc[0].push(value);
            acc[1].push(...errors);
            return acc;
        },
        [[], []] as TOutput<P>
    );
}

let unionZip = zipFN3([2, []], ['A', []])
// OK, [(string|number)[], Error[]]

let UnionInstances = zipFN3( [new Date(), []], [console, []], [new RegExp('[A-Z]'), []])
// OK, [(Regexp|Date|Console)[], Error[]]
```

Comment: Awesome answer ! I changed Error types to Error values as you mentioned, I thought that part was not so important. Sorry for my ignorance but are there special name for `<T, P extends TParam<T>[]>` so I can check docs. It's still a bit ambiguous for me since I don't know that usage.

Comment: One last thing to ask, at line 11 https://replit.com/@baturalpgurdin/zip#index.ts compiler yells at me `Conversion of type '[never[], never[]]' to type 'TOutput<P>'` should I convert it to unknown then `'TOutput<P>'` or is there a better way to give initial value to reduce parameter.

Comment: in my environment it didn't complained, nor in TS Playground, but it did in codesandbox, see how I solved it: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-144cd . Normally TS won't deem empty arrays to be never[], it does when there's not enough info to figure types out